# Why don't my multiline textviews have the same height?

Tags: android, textview, multiline

I have 3 textviews with 2 lines. I placed them in the horizontal `LinearLayout` with same weight. The problem is that when I put text into this `TextView`s, they have different heights if text take up 1 line or 2 lines. This behavior is strange.

[image: image of current state]

I need 3 text views with the same height regardless to the text length.

`my_layout.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:gravity="bottom">
   <TextView
       style="@style/style"
       android:text="TextView1" />
   <TextView
       style="@style/style"
       android:text="Long text Textview2" />
   <TextView
       style="@style/style"
       android:text="TextView3" />
</LinearLayout>
```

`styles.xml`:

```
<style name="style">
    <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:lines">2</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/txt_size_30</item>
</style>
```

Comment: You set layout_height to wrap_content.

Comment: Do anybody know, why this is happening? There is wrap_content but also there is set exact number of lines, so why TextViews has different heights?

Comment: It's a good question and I can't find a logical answer. The lines=2 should suppose to take care of the height from the beginning, no matter if the text is on one line or two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set layout_height with some height rather than using wrap_content.

`WRAP_CONTENT` :
Special value for the height or width requested by a View.

WRAP_CONTENT will change the height according to view requirement.

**Update**

You can use ConstraintLayout. Here all the TextView height matches with height of long textView(TextView 2)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#dedede"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:text="textview 1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/textView2"

        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:background="#dedede"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/textView1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:text="long textView 2"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:background="#dedede"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:text="textView 3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/textView2"
        />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I don't want to use hard-coded height. Hard-coded height solve this problem but it's not responsive. User can change font size in device settings.